# Using must and should in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data in format below:

```
{
   "name": "a school",
   "type": "school", // Either school, university or dorm
   "city": "Konya",
   "district": "Selçuklu",
   "dorm_type": null,
   "dorm_gender": null,
   "school_type": "private", // Either public or private or mix
   "uni_type": null,
},
{
   "name": "some univeristy",
   "type": "university", // Either school, university or dorm
   "city": "Istanbul",
   "district": "Besiktas",
   "dorm_type": null,
   "dorm_gender": null,
   "school_type": "null", 
   "uni_type": "private", // Either public or private
},
{
   "name": "some dormitory",
   "type": "dormitory", // Either school, university or dormitory
   "city": "Istanbul",
   "district": "Besiktas",
   "dorm_type": "private", // Either public or private
   "dorm_gender": "boys", // Either boys or girls
   "school_type": "null", 
   "uni_type": "null", 
}
```

```
{
  "size": 500,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "`*q*`",
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "Istanbul"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "district": "Beşiktaş"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "dorm_type": "public"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "dorm_gender": "boys"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "school_type": "private"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "uni_type": "public"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is my query correct if I want search to show one or more than one filteration?
The query is just an example. I tried to use both *must* and *should* because *must* means AND and this is valid to show city or district. But for school, university and dorm types and gender you only have one of them filled and others are null. For instance I may search for showing only public universities or maybe public universities and public dorms.
I am kind of confused.

Comment: @Agnels, showing your expected output for your queries would be helpful for community to help you.

Comment: The problem is with filteration which doesnt give me the result I wish. I have written other info in the question.

Answer (score 0):

must and should is AND

- query in must is AND
- query in should is OR